# iOS UITextView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I'm going to try to explain my problem as best I can.
I have a UIViewController, and inside that view I used the storyboard to drag an UITextView. My goal here is reading the touch points the user clicks on the UITextView, through the touchesBegin and touchesEnded methods. To do this I created a custom class called TextView, and on the storyboard I told that the class that is handling the UITextView is the new one. Doing that I can read the touch points when I click on the UITextView, but now I want to send that touch point data, back to the UIViewController, I'm trying to do this for 2 days now and nothing works!! I tried to create a delegate but without successs.

Comment: "My goal here is reading the touch points the user clicks on the UITextView, through the touchesBegin and touchesEnded methods" If you don't know how to do this, do not prejudice your possible answer by saying what methods the answer must involve. Just explain what you want to _do_. Do you want to know what word the user taps on? What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion i will to elaborate a bit better. What i want to do is, having a big chunk of text that the user can scroll to read, and while he does that i wanna read is touch point entrys, through the use of touchesBegan. I already have done a similiar job, but only when i have a single viewcontroller, if i create a uitextview inside this viewcontroller and add it has a subview and delegate i cant communicate more data then the ones in the standard delegate

Answer (score -1):

Make an instance of your custom class in your ViewController.m and use your methods to get the touch data inside your viewcontroller.